# Looking for a Regex only match uppercases and ignore web link

Tags: regex

i'm looking for a Regex only matching a certain number of uppercases and ignore uppercases in web link.

Here is an example i'm looking for :

ABCDEFG : Matching
abcDEFG : Matching
https://stackoverflow.com/ABCDEFG : not matching

I try this and it's work perfectly for the 2 examples but matching the web link too :

```
[A-Z][A-Z\d]{5,}
```

Comment: Your pattern can not match `abcDEFG` Perhaps like this `(?:^| )\w*([A-Z][A-Z\d]{3,})(?:$| )`   See https://regex101.com/r/DWsB81/1

Answer (score 0):

You could use a negative lookahead in front of the pattern to exclude URLs:

```
^(?!https?://).*[A-Z]{3,}.*$
```

The above would match any input having three or more continuous capital letters, and so would match:

```
ABCDEFG
abcdEFG
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but why it doesn't work with rustexp editor ? https://rustexp.lpil.uk

Comment: @Gilles My answer is working [in this demo](https://regex101.com/r/768FI9/).  Maybe your regex engine does not support negative lookaheads.

Comment: Yes i have this error : "look-around, including look-ahead and look-behind, is not supported"

I'm searching for another solution.

Comment: What tool or programming language are you using with your regex?

Comment: It's Rust used by Discord automod tool : https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/10069840290711-Filter-Messages-Using-Regular-Expressions-Regex-

Comment: If you can't use lookaround, maybe something like this could work (it's not perfect, but can be improved):

use a regex replace function with this pattern, replace with $1

`()(http[^A-Z]+[A-Z]{3,})|([^ֿA-Z\n]+[A-Z]{3,}[^ֿA-Z\n]+)`

https://regex101.com/r/SEQ6vY/1

() - creates an empty capture group ($1)
(http[^A-Z]+[A-Z]{3,}) - matches http followed by non upper case letters followed by 3 or more upper case letters. If this part matches, it should be replaced by the empty capture group.
If it doesn't match, the pattern will look for:
([^ֿA-Z\n]+[A-Z]{3,}[^ֿA-Z\n]+)